# one button two different actions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to development section . I have a small clarification in Jquery . A single button should possess two different action . Let us consider a button name Pause/Resume if i click on pause button it should alert as pause by clicking on same button it has to display resume .

```
var flag = false;
$("#btn_pause_resume").click(function (){
if (flag)
{

alert("pause");
}
else
{
alert("Resume");
flag = true;
}
```

Comment: is your code not working? if you want it to alert `pause` first, you need to swap your code in the `if`/`else`. Is this in a `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function(){`?

Comment: @Sean it is in $(document).ready(function(){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite way is to use attributes (data). Kind of like:

```
<button data-paused="false"></button>
```

Here's a solution:

```
$('#btn_pause_resume').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('paused')==='false') {
        alert('Resumed...');
        $(this).data('paused', 'true');
    } else {
        alert('Paused...');
        $(this).data('paused', 'false');
    }
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLf9ju93/)

---

## Quick Plugin

Here's a plugin I just wrote that will make this easy:

```
$.fn.toggleClick=function(t,a,e){$(this).data("ToggleState",e||false),this.click(function(){"false"===$(this).data("ToggleState")?(t(),$(this).data("ToggleState","true")):(a(),$(this).data("ToggleState","false"))})};
```

Add this to the top of your code and you can do:

```
$('#btn_pause_resume').toggleClick(
function () {
    alert('Resumed!');
},
function () {
    alert('Paused!');
}, true);//True makes second function run first
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLf9ju93/2/)

This adds a `toggleClick` function. This function takes two functions which each run.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var flag = false;
            $("#btn_pause_resume").click(function (){
                if (flag)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    alert("pause");
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = true;
                    alert("Resume");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Or a `flag=!flag` outside of the `if/else` statements. Or `if((flag=!flag)){alert('Resume');}else{alert('Pause');}` which would be even shorter. Or `alert((flag=!flag)?'Resume':'Pause')`…

Answer (score 0):

Here is your player with playStatus property

> var playStatus = false; (which is pause)
>
> ```
> $("#button").click(function(){
> playStatus = !playStatus;
> });
> ```

with that just check against playStatus variable. if(playStatus){alert ....}

Answer (score 0):

the first thing I notices was that the ckick function need the closing parenthesis at the end of the code. the if statement should check specifically for false. I also recommend using the triple equal to ensure that you are checking for that particular type.

This should work.

```
var flag = false;
$("#btn_pause_resume").click(function (){
    if (flag === false) {
        alert("pause");
    } else {
        alert("Resume");
        flag = true;
    {    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
   var btn=  document.getElementById("btn");
    if(btn.innerHTML=="Pause")
    btn.innerHTML="Resume";
  else
      btn.innerHTML="Pause";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```